# <picture> element has unexpected behaviour on iOS

Tags: ios, image, srcset

I'm using the `<picture>` element with `srcset` to load different images for different screen resolutions. This is for art direction reasons - I'm wanting different shapes - so I need to use `<picture>`.

The issue I'm having is that it doesn't work on iOS - neither Chrome nor Safari. This is despite the info on Can I Use indicating that it should: https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset

```
    <picture>
       <source media="(min-width: 62em)" srcset="hero-home.jpg" sizes="100vw">
       <source media="(min-width: 48em)" srcset="hero-home-991x490.jpg" sizes="100vw">
       <source media="(min-width: 34.375em)" srcset="hero-home-767x460.jpg" sizes="100vw">
       <source srcset="hero-home-549x575.jpg">
       <img src="hero-home.jpg" class="crop">
    </picture>
```

I'm also using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`, which I think is one of the common fixes for this problem.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything correctly, but on iOS (and iOS only), it briefly loads the correct picture and then flicks to the 62em `srcset`.

Has anyone come across this behaviour before? Is it some weird retina thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I eventually worked this one out!

iOS - and looks like any Mac OS as well - doesn't like me using `ems` as the units. Changed to pixels and BOOM. Works exactly as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I don't love the idea of pixels for breakpoints, but this'll have to do!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `REM`s or `EM`s within the `<picture>` element.  Much as you may prefer it in design terms, it doesn't make quite so much sense in real life.

**Here's an explanation for the problem:**

The  `<picture>` element was developed to solve a specific problem.  That problem was waiting until the page was loaded to decide which image to use.

The `<img` tag, is great, it offers alt text, it's accessible.  But previously the best way to make an image responsive was to use a background image, then you could determine which shape and size to use.

Once decided you could serve a significantly smaller image for mobile (and a different shape).  But then you lost the accessible nature of images, and not all images suited being a background image.

Then you had the option to serve images and replace them but sometimes that meant loading a mobile image on desktop, or worse, loading a huge desktop image on mobile and then replacing with a suitable image (or simply allowing it to resize).  So on a mobile device you were loading images twice on a slower speed.  That was a boon.

The idea is that when fetching a page, you can preload resources, CSS, images etc.  When calling the DOM it can also call the CSS and start loading it.  In the past you would put all the JS at the bottom of the page to speed up load times (no longer a requirement).  This was to stop those resources from blocking rendering.  But you couldn't preload background images, you had to read the CSS first, which is more like post-loading.

For that reason `srcset` and `<picture>` were invented which enables preloading of the correct image on the `<img` tag.  When you call the DOM you can start download the CSS and the images at the same time.

**EMs and REMs**

Now... we move onto `EM`s and `REM`s.  These are relative measurements.  To understand an EM you need the parent container measurement as `EM`s relate to the parent.  `REM`s relate to the body/default measurement.  This would mean needing to wait for CSS to load to understand those measurements/units.

With HTTP2 we can load more resources at the same time, which means we can start to download images as we fetch the DOM and CSS.  `<picture>` and `srcset` is the thing that lets that happen, BUT it won't know what an `EM` is at that point in the loading process so it potentially could load the wrong image if it guessed, or else it would just wait until page load, so again, we're not preloading.  So that's why you have to use `px`.

I hope that makes sense (and I hope my understanding is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/) to see which of the newer HTML5 elements are supported whenever there's a doubt.

In this specific scenario it could be a combined issue of any of the following:

the lack of support of the `<picture>` element
 using only the `min-width` versus `max-width` property
 not using responsive measurements to detect the correct viewport size for 
 fallbacks (e.g.: using 50vw for instance)

Comment: Where are you seeing this info on Can I Use? All I can see is that it says it is supported for iOS Safari.